# Checking status of a command in a pipeline

Tags: bash

I want to `grep` for a string and cut a field if there is a match. Problem is that, no matter if there is a match or not, the output of the command `$?` is 0 which is weird. Please see the output below:

```
$ R=`grep g09 tor1.sh | cut -d ' ' -f2`
$ echo $R
test
$ R=`grep g09 tor1.sh | cut -d ' ' -f2`
$ echo $?
0
```

As you can see, there is a match but `$?` is 0. Now see this:

```
$ R=`grep g09 tor.sh | cut -d ' ' -f2`
$ echo $R

$ R=`grep g09 tor.sh | cut -d ' ' -f2`
$ echo $?
0
```

Here, there is no match for g09 but `$?` is still 0. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$?` is the overall or final exit status. What you need to look at is a bash array named:

```
PIPESTATUS
```

That gives you status of individual piped command.

So for you case:

```
read str < <(grep g09 tor.sh | cut -d ' ' -f2`)

echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
1
```

Here `1` means failure of first grep command in pipeline.

**PS: Please note that we're using process substitution, instead of command substitution to be able to set `PIPESTATUS` correctly in current shell.**

**Example:**

```
read str < <(grep 'bar' <<< 'foo bar baz' | cut -d ' ' -f2)
echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
0

read str < <(grep 'cat' <<< 'foo bar baz' | cut -d ' ' -f2)
echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
1
```

In the first example `grep` runs successfully hence we get `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` as 0 but `1` in 2nd example when `grep` fails to find anything.

Comment: As pointed out by @bishop in the follow up question, `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` above won't yield the right result because the pipeline is being run in a subshell.  Your examples are fine because there is no subshell being used there.

Comment: Very good point @codeforester. I have modified answer to use process substitution to be able to get `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` correctly.