# Checking the output of a piped grep

Tags: bash, grep

I want to check the output of `grep` command piped to another command. In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521890/checking-status-of-a-command-in-a-pipeline), PIPESTATUS has been suggested but now I see that it doesn't fully work for all conditions. No matter what is the output of `grep` (match or unmatch), the `PIPESTATUS` returns 0 which is weird.

The script contains

```
GF=`grep g09 $INP | cut -d ' ' -f2`
if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]}  = 1 ]; then
```

Basically, the first command searches for `g09` in the input file. If it doesn't exist, the PIPESTATUS should be `1`.

Now suing `set -x` in the bash script, I see that for an input file which contains g09, the output is 0 and for an input which has no g09 in it, the output is still 0

```
++ grep g09 tor.sh
++ cut -d ' ' -f2
+ GF=hashe.gjf
+ '[' 0 = 1 ']'
```

and

```
++ grep g09 tor.sh
++ cut -d ' ' -f2
+ GF=
+ '[' 0 = 1 ']'
```

Why? How can I fix that? Is there any solution other than PIPESTATUS?

Comment: Please paste the full code.

Comment: As you can see in the output of `set -x`, it is an input file `tor.sh`. There are two `tor.sh` in two different directories. The full code may be large, but I will update the post

Comment: The backticks are running your commands in a separate process which is why the environment variable is no longer available to your calling script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why?

The command substitution is run in a subshell. When the subshell exits, the result of its status fills `PIPESTATUS`, overwriting what was there from within the subshell.

> How can I fix that?

Check the PIPESTATUS inside the sub-shell.

```
$(grep g09 $INPUT | cut -f2 -d' '; [[ 1 == $PIPESTATUS[0] ]] && { ... })
```

Comment: Well that {...} contains multiple lines. That was the reason I didn't paste the full code (though it is unnecessary). Isn't there a simple method?

Answer (score 2):

For your case, you could simply check if the value extracted through `cut` is empty or not.

```
if [[ -z $GF ]]; then
```

Comment: That mean empty or not empty?

Comment: Checking for emptiness, in line with the fact that you were checking for `grep's` exit code of 1.  `[[ -z $GF ]]` is true when GF is empty (not set or is of zero length).

Comment: Not really... A simpler method than PIPESTATUS is also OK.

Comment: @codeforester: You don't need a variable for this, just check the return code of `grep` directly in if condition